# ResourceDictionary Style Error: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, mvvmcross, resourcedictionary

I have existing Windows 8.1 application running on Windows tab 8.1 also,
I created that on Windows 8.1 OS and Visual studio 2013 before then when i move to Windows 10 OS and Visual studio 2015 Update 3 there was an exception and upon investigation. Some properties of ListViewItemPresenter causing the exception on runtime.
that 3 properties are

1. **HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding
   HorizontalContentAlignment}"**
2. **VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding
   VerticalContentAlignment}"**
3. **Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"**

The ListviewItem style is located on separate file Resource Dictionary,
but when i try to put all style in same file (AppBarMenu.xaml) the style is working and no error was throw.

**Note:** I used MVVMCROSS framework to this application and the error happens when i swiped or tapped the application.

Below is the XAML style in resource dictionary.

```
 <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle_Menu" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,18,2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
                        CheckHintBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}"
                        CheckSelectingBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}"
                        CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}"
                        DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                        DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                        FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}"
                        PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                        PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                        SelectedBorderThickness="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCompactSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"
                        SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                        SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"
                        SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                        SelectedPointerOverBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"
                        DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                        DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                        ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        PointerOverBackgroundMargin="1"
                        ContentMargin="2" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and in my Listview here's the XAML (AppBarMenu.xaml)

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="{Binding IconUri}"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,0,0,-5">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BaseColor01}"/>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform Rotation="45"/>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Border Grid.Row="1" Height="60" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BaseColor01}"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   Margin="15,0"
                                   FontWeight="SemiLight"
                                   FontSize="24" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   Grid.Row="1" 
                                   TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,7,0">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BaseColor02}"/>
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6" Margin="3,0">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BaseColor02}"/>
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BaseColor02}"/>
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3">
                                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6" Margin="3,0">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BaseColor02}"/>
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BaseColor02}"/>
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BaseColor02}"/>
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Border Background="#01000000" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <b:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                    <ctrls:MediaElementPlayAction />
                                    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=Selected}" />
                                </b:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

If someone encounter this same problem kindly share your idea what are the reason of this error.

**NOTE: I'm not looking for the answers or the solution , I'm just looking for the reasons why is it happen.**

Thanks Guys.

Comment: "there was an error?"  Do you mean a runtime error, a compiler error, or an error in the designer?  What IS the error?  Why do you think we don't need to know what the error is in order to answer your question?  The mind boggles.

Comment: If you read and understand my note above said

"Note: I used MVVMCROSS framework to this application and the error happens when i swiped or tapped the application."

I think we can't swipe the application during compiling, meaning it's occur during runtime. Thank you